# Command line: changing white balance & contracts of screen

Tags: command-line, screen, colors, gnome-color-manager

I have I got modded Lenovo x230 with FHD screen via dock connection with board. One of the thing is, that colors are little off. Before reinstalling my OS, I had command line (I forgotten) which I use to change white balance (white point). I found it off on some youtube video, but I can not find it again. (Because of the chip, spyder for calibration or similar hdw solutions things does now work.)

Please anybody can advice me, what is the command line to change white balance of screen, or where I can find the some more info?

Thanks
PS: I am on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You can either use GUI either terminal. For GUI, please find the solution here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-night-light.html.en For terminal, here: https://www.debugpoint.com/2020/10/adjust-color-temperature-ubuntu-terminal/

Comment: Hello, sct command does not seem to work. I was hoping for this one also before.

Comment: I resolved it over custom gnome. But I can not get contrast to set it up.